# C# Classes, Interfaces and Constraints

Tags: c#, oop

I have a project where I need to achieve the following :

Say I have an  interface called "ITemplate" and I define a number of classes "templates" based on that interface.

- TemplateA
- TemplateB
- ....
- TemplateZ

If I want create a LIST of any templates I can use

```
List<ITemplate> myList = new List<ITemplate>();
myList.Add(TemplateA);
myList.Add(TemplateC);
myList.Add(TemplateX);
```

etc - that's fine.

Say now I want to create a number of special lists so that

myListAlphaTemplates can only have a defined subset of all templates, and
myListBetaTemplates can only have a different defined subset of all templates

What is the best way to achieve this?

So the code i have at the moment is along the lines of the following ( the real code is too large to post)

Define the template interface

```
interface ITemplateConstraint 
{ }
```

Define more interfaces for each list type

```
interface SpecialListOne : ITemplateConstraint
{ }

interface SpecialListTwo : ITemplateConstraint
{ }
```

Now I define an actual "template"

```
public class TemplateA : SpecialListOne , SpecialListTwo 
{     ....    }

public class TemplateB : SpecialListOne 
{     ....    }

public class TemplateC : SpecialListTwo 
{     ....    }
```

And finally I add my lists

```
List<SpecialListOne> ListofTypeOne;   // this can be TemplateA  or TemplateB 
List<SpecialListTwo> ListofTypeTwo;   // this can be TemplateA  or TemplateC
```

This works fine, but..

If all of the templates are in a separate library and I have a need to create a new list "SpecialListThree" which only has TemplateC in it, is there a way of doing this without have to amend the actual template definitions themselves?

Comment: Please post code that will compile - C# is case sensitive, `LIST<> != List<>`.

Comment: `can only have a defined subset of all templates` Which out knowing the conditions of the subset I don't know how to help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if your want to constrain lists by `Type` then you can use code such as

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T> where T:ITemplate, new() { }  

var specialList1 = new MyList<TemplateA>();
var specialList2 = new MyList<TemplateB>();
```

If constraining is on arbitrary condition then you probably need to write your own class wrapping inner list implementation. But constraining will happen at runtime rather than compile time. For example:

```
public class ConstrainedList<T> : IList<T> where T:ITemplate
{
    private List<T> _inner = new List<T>();
    Func<T, bool> _constraint;

    public ConstrainedList<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
       _constraint = predicate;
    }

    #Region IList Implementation

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (_constraint(item))
        {
           _inner.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
           throw new ArgumentException("Does not meet necessary constraint");
        }
    }

    // rest of implementation
    ...

    #End Region
}

var specialList1 = new ConstrainedList<ITemplate>(t => null != t && typeof(TemplateA) == t.GetType());
var specialList2 = new ConstrainedList<ITemplate>(t => null != t && t.SomeMethod() >= 3);
```

Answer (score 4):

Its pretty simple, any `Enumerable<>` has the extension method `OfType<>`.

An example of its use would be:

```
var myList = new List<ITemplate>();
myList.Add(TemplateA);
myList.Add(TemplateC);
myList.Add(TemplateX);

var myListAlphaTemplates = myList.OfType<AlphaTemplateClass>().ToList();
```

Comment: i like this a lot. just load them all up and filter the list :) Much simpler than my approach

Comment: +1 but technically `List<>` does not have the method - it's an extension that can be applied to any `IEnumerable<>`

Comment: Hmm, that's more of a filtering solution is it not? Currently the code would know what templates are allowed in each list and stop this at compile time. That may not be achievable with the flexibility I want, but I really want to stop an invalid template being added to the list, not filter it out after it has been added.

Comment: Actually, maybe extension methods is the answer. I could create my own extension to add the template to the list, and build in the logic within the extension method..

Answer (score 1):

You can make interfaces for your alpha and beta templates, based on ITemplate, and have your specific classes implement those:

```
IAlphaTemplate : ITemplate {}

IBetaTemplate : ITemplate {}

TemplateA : IAlphaTemplate {}

TemplateB : IBetaTemplate {}

// etc.

var myListAlphaTemplates = new List<IAlphaTemplate>();
var myListBetaTemplates = new List<IBetaTemplate>();
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the way it currently is. The problem I have is that if I need a new special list say 'GammaTemplates', is there a way of achieving that without having to open up all the code for the existing templates - which in my case will be in a separate assembly shared between a number of applications.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any logic to it, make the special classes inherit from an abstract special class which implements the interface, or make them implement a special interface that inherits from the regular one.

Otherwise, you cant inforce it.

Answer (score 0):

You could define an abstract class that implements the interface, and then inherit from that to define your concrete implementations.

Answer (score -1):

```
interface IQalifiedTemplate
{
     bool IsQaulified(args);
     ITemaplate Template {get;}
}
```

or

```
interface IQalifiedTemplate
   : ITemplate
{
     bool IsQaulified(args);
}
```

you can use IsQualified(...) to determine if it should be added to the list.

Comment: He doesn't need to KNOW whether to add or not, hw wants a lsi that CAN only contain the special ones - INFORCE it. Otherwise he could just check if object is class.

Comment: you can use this to determine if you can add it to the list. thus enforcing what can be added.

Comment: The list will still be able to contain other types of ITemplate. What you suggest is not enforcing - it is filtering. And again, for simple filtering he doesn't need a bool property.

Comment: i'm not disagreeing with you i'm approaching the problem differently. enforcement would be done at another level with this approach. personally I like @Jeff's approach the most. KISS!